Why did Kosmo not reveal the truth after the ritual?
In the sixth season of The Dragon Prince, the time-blind Celestial skywing elf Kosmo noticed that the

orb that Rayla and Callum had brought with them was actually the fake, made of candy.

Kosmo then chose not to tell Callum and Rayla that they had actually taken the imitation orb, after seeing in a vision that this would sap Callum's motivation to perform the ritual that would purify him of the effects of dark magic, concluding that telling them at that point would be counterproductive. Indeed, after Kosmo decided not to share the information, Callum performed the ritual.
However, why did Kosmo not tell them after Callum had successfully completed the ritual? Presumably, this truth was of great importance (i.e. not without "purpose") since knowing it might have allowed them to return to Katolis and secure the orb before Claudia could use it to release Aaravos: Callum and Rayla spent at least a few hours with Lujanne before Claudia and Callum performed their respective resurrections, and since the smoke from Katolis was visible from where they were, they were a short flight away.

The answer to this is implied by some dialogue in the seventh season. The leader of the Celestial elves said that their tradition was to observe only and to not intervene by sharing the visions that they had been granted; in all likelihood, Kosmo presumably at least partly agreed with this perspective, and his visions would only have increased his belief in the necessity of avoiding any interference.
Furthermore, they might have been thinking positively and hoping that despite the pearls having been switched, Rayla and Callum would return to Katolis and realize that the orb that was there was the real one, which they would then be able to address more effectively, since Callum would no longer be vulnerable to the control of Aaravos. Notably, once Kosmo realized that Aaravos had indeed escaped, rendering this reasoning invalid, Astrid went to warn Rayla, and Kosmo helped her by sharing his visions in defiance of the leader.
